# Why change in LD_LIBRARY_PATH at Runtime dosen't Reflect on the Executable once the Executable gets loaded

Tags: c++, linux, setenv, getenv

I'm trying to change the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` from my C++ program. I'm able to get its value using `getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH")` and set its value using [`setenv()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setenv.3.html) (and I know that this is working, because when I call `getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH")` again, I get the updated value), but changing its value from inside the program isn't having any effect on it: I still get this error-message:

> `Failed to Load the shared library file`

If I set the value before the executable gets loaded or the application is started, it works fine.

Comment: I would simply code a shell wrapper which sets appropriately the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before `exec`-ing the binary ELF executable. This is common practice (most distributions are doing this for `firefox`)

Comment: hi [Basile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/841108/basile-starynkevitch) thanks for your response right. I'm trying to write a shell wrapper as you said , But the problem is i need to run the script as 

. filename.sh (in the terminal)

then only the export path works. if I try to start my application at system start up ,I'm not able to achieve the same .

Comment: No, just `chmod a+x filename.sh`, put `filename.sh` inside some directory in your `PATH` and you can run it simply as `filename.sh`

Comment: I'm starting my application at system start up with application.sh which executes the filename.sh(shell script to set path) but it dosen't work ,the path is not set

Comment: Then use a full path like e.g. `$HOME/bin/filename.sh` or `/usr/local/bin/filename.sh`. Look inside `firefox` or `mozilla` ; it is generally a shell script....

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unfortunately setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` from within a running program will have no effect on it.  The reason for this is that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is processed by the dynamic link loader (ld.so), which is the program which starts your program. Your program itself doesn't process `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` so changing it will have no effect.

Comment: Changing `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` has no effect, except if the program calls  after `dlopen` to load a plugin.

Comment: Agreed. Any child processes (of the original process) would inherit a change in LD_LIBRARY_PATH made within that original process.  So, setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH within your program, then forking and killing the parent should put you where (I presume) you want to be in terms of the load path.