# How to help iJulia notebook find an externally compiled library

Tags: julia, ijulia-notebook, mxnet.jl

I am trying to run a compiled version of mxnet in an [iJulia](https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl) notebook, but when I execute the command `using MXNet`, I get the follow error:

```
InitError: error compiling __init__: error compiling _populate_symbol_creator_cache!: error compiling _get_atomic_symbol_creators: could not load library "/home/milton/mxnet/lib/libmxnet.so"
libcudart.so.7.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
during initialization of module mx

in _include_from_serialized(::String) at ./loading.jl:150
in _require_from_serialized(::Int64, ::Symbol, ::String, ::Bool) at ./loading.jl:187
in _require_search_from_serialized(::Int64, ::Symbol, ::String, ::Bool) at ./loading.jl:217
in require(::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:371
```

Figuring it might be ENV getting cleared, I added:

```
ENV["MXNET_HOME"] = "/home/milton/mxnet"
ENV["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] = "/home/milton/mxnet/lib:/usr/local/cuda/lib64"
```

This allows me to execute the instruction `using MXNet` without error, but raises the error again when trying to execute any commands from the mxnet library

```
error compiling #Variable#215: could not load library "/home/milton/programming/mxnet/lib/libmxnet.so"
libcudart.so.7.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

in Variable(::Symbol) at /home/milton/.julia/v0.5/MXNet/src/symbolic-node.jl:232
```

How do I fix this?  Is there somewhere else I need to define the path? Everything works fine from the REPL.

Answer (score 1):

I got this working with some help on [GitHub](https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl/issues/517).  I learned there that the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is processed by the dynamic link loader and fixed when the program is started as described in the answer to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19337926/why-change-in-ld-library-path-at-runtime-dosent-reflect-on-the-executable-once).  Even though it appears changed when messing with it in the notebook, it isn't.

To get this to work, I start `jupyter-notebook` in a terminal with the proper `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set (in my case my `.bashrc` automatically includes a path to my compiled `mxnet/lib`, so it works in any local terminal. It isn't in my global setup).